# Multiple files view in email template laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, notifications

I have an array of image path to attach with email. How can i view them in a email template?

SendMailController:

```
  $files = collect(json_decode($img_files))->map(function ($file) {
    return public_path('uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file->name);
  })->toArray();

  Mail::to($customer_email)->send(new SendMail($customer_firstname, $pathToFile), function($message){
        foreach ($files as $filePath) {
            $message->attach($filePath);
        }
      }
  );
```

In my email template:

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed($filePath) }}" style="width:600px;height:335px">
```

But this gives, `Undefined variable: filePath` error. How can i this

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
Mail::to($customer_email)->send(
    new SendMail($customer_firstname, $files), function($message){
        $size = sizeOf($files); //get the count of number of attachments 

        for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
            $message->attach($files[$i]);
        }

    }
);
```